# read more option react-native-gifted-chat

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need read more option in react-native-gifted-chat like WhatsApp

I tried by doing this

```js
let messages = [{
  _id: id,
  text: <Text numberOfLines = {3} style={{height: 40}}>{text}</Text>,
  createdAt: new Date(),
  quickReplies: {
    type: "radio",
    keepIt: true,
    values: options? options: []
  },
  user: { 
    _id: direction,
    name: userName,
    avatar: image
  }
}]
setMessages(previousMessages => GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, messages))
```

but not working can any one help me?